# VBScript Label Expression ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, labeling, vbscript

Not sure what I am doing wrong. The expression is valid, but the results are that nothing labels at all. This is the function:

```
Function FindLabel ( [Address], [Building], [Unit] )

If (IsNull[Unit]) And (IsNull[Building]) Then
          FindLabel = [Address]

ElseIf (Not IsNull[Building]) And (IsNull[Unit]) Then
          FindLabel = [Address] + vbNewLine + [Building]

ElseIf (IsNull[Building]) And (Not IsNull[Unit]) Then
          FindLabel = [Address] + vbNewLine + [Unit]

End If

End Function
```

Comment: what if both Unit and Building is present? Your function would do nothing for this case

Answer (score 1):

It's been a *very* long time since I used VBScript, but I think `IsNull` is a function so should use parentheses, i.e. `IsNull([FIELD])` instead of `IsNull[FIELD]`.

You should also add an `Else` clause for when both fields contain values.

Also, check  you have actually enabled labels. Right click layer and check the "Label" menu entry is highlighted with a box around its icon. Label is directly above the Labelling Properties... entry.